# JBoss Seam are not scaning external jar components

Tags: java, seam

I have created a external module project for a main project, but when i try to inject a component seam of the external module in the main project, then a nullpointer occurs, because JBoss seam could not find the component in the external jar

I am using jboss seam version 2.3.1.Final

Answer (score 0):

To Seam Scan external jars it is necessary to have a file seam.properties in classpath of this external jar.

If you add a blank file "seam.properties" in the class path of your module project (src/main/resources), seam will scan the components of this project, and the main project will be able to use this components.